# Another BC30002: Type is not defined

Tags: asp.net, dll, types, defined

Here's what I've done...

I used wsdl.exe to create a .cs class for my wsdl service connection.
I made a Visual Studio project to compile the .cs into a dll having namespace CalculatorService (CalculatorService.dll).
Successful thus far.

I created an asp.net project added my namespace import:

```
%@ Import Namespace="CalculatorService" %
```

I right-clicked on the project, clicked Add Reference, found my .dll, added it, built the project, checked /bin to ensure my dll was there (and it was).

```
%
'I called the namespace:'
Dim calcService As New CalculatorService.CalculatorService()
'called the function from the service'
Dim xmlResult = calcService.GetSVS_ItemTable_XML("", "", "", "", "", "")
'printed the result'
Response.Write(xmlResult)
%
```

All is well LOCALLY while debugging.  It found the CalculatorService, connected to it, got the XML and displayed it.

I then wanted to put it on the web so I built and published my project:
under "Copy" - Only files needed to run this application...selected!

Deploying on the web says Type 'CalculatorService.CalculatorService' is not defined.

Here is a link to the live script:
http://vansmith.com/_iaps.wsdl/pub/Default.aspx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some how you are missing the registration of some assembly; and precisely, in this case, the `CalculatorService.dll`. See if you have added the `<%@ Register... >` tag in your page that is calling the calculator methods.